# Using MSDeploy to copy/clone website in IIS 7

Tags: iis, msdeploy

I am trying to clone a website in IIS (testing on IIS 7.x on Win8 but to be run on Server 2008) to essentially create a complete copy of the app and the definition of a website and all child applications. I don't want to copy the contents.

For instance, if my original website is listed as ID 2 with name "dev.mydomain.com", I want to create a new website with ID 3 (for example) with name of "stage.mydomain.com".

The Physical Path points to "c:\dev.mydomain.com", which has to be changed to "c:\stage.mydomain.com". There are nested apps within this site that will also just need their Physical Path changing. I'm ok going into the xml file and just doing a manual search/replace, in fact, that would probably make it easier.

So my attempt was:

To export:

```
msdeploy -verb:sync -source:metakey=lm/w3svc/2 -dest:archiveDir=somefolder -skip:objectName=filePath,absolutePath=.*
```

To import:

```
msdeploy -verb:sync -source:archiveDir=somefolder -dest:metakey=lm/w3svc/3
```

I can go into the xml files in the folder and rename the paths, but when I run the import I get errors about the "path" /metakey is encrypted. I've tried other combinations but get different errors.

Is there an easier way to do this or can anyone give me the correct command?

Thanks.